# Display error in Laravel 5.3 against each field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a form with some validations. After the validations, I need to display the error against each input field and I tried to do it using `$errors->first('organizations')` but this doesn't seem to work and I get the `$errors->first('organizations')` printed on my screen. Below is the snippet of my code. Can somebody point out what I am doing wrong?

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('organization') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label class="control-label" style="{{ $errors->has('organization') ? '' : 'display:none !important;' }}" for="organization"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> {{ $errors->has('organization') ? '$errors->first("organization")' : '' }}</label>
    <select class="form-control" placeholder="Organization" id="organization" name="organization">
        <option value="0" style="display: none !important;" disabled selected>Organization</option>
        @foreach ($organizations as $organizations)
            <option value="{{ $organizations->orgid }}">{{ $organizations->orgname }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You should remove the ' around $errors->first('organizations'), as this converts it to a non-php code and a string.

Comment: Yes true, I realized that now changed the code as `@if($errors->has('organization'))
   <label class="control-label" for="organization"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> {{ $errors->first('organization') }}</label>
  @endif` this solves my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer myself and this seemed to be a better way to handle the error messages. Just leaving it here for other new comers.

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('organization') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
        @if($errors->has('organization'))
            <label class="control-label" for="organization"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> {{ $errors->first('organization') }}</label>
        @endif
        <select class="form-control" placeholder="Organization" id="organization" name="organization">
            <option value="0" style="display: none !important;" disabled selected>Organization</option>
            @foreach ($organizations as $organizations)
                <option value="{{ $organizations->orgid }}">{{ $organizations->orgname }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code , which I used in my view file

```
 <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('email')) has-error @endif has-feedback">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" >
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
          @if ($errors->has('email')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</p> @endif
     </div>
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You should write this. This will solve your problem

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('organization') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
   @if($errors->has('organization'))
       <label class="control-label" for="organization"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> {{ $errors->first('organization') }}</label>
   @endif
   <select class="form-control" placeholder="Organization" id="organization" name="organization">
       <option value="0" style="display: none !important;" disabled selected>Organization</option>
       @foreach ($organizations as $organizations)
          <option value="{{ $organizations->orgid }}">{{ $organizations->orgname }}</option>
       @endforeach
   </select>
</div>
```